# Flash Javascript interface

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Say I have this javascript function:

```
    function updateMainBuff(buff) {
                // do some stuff
    }
```

I have this function in my Flash project (full source here: [bitly.com/SnyhGT](http://bitly.com/SnyhGT) ) :

```
protected function recordSampleDataHandler(event:SampleDataEvent):void
                    {       
                            while(event.data.bytesAvailable)
                            {       
                                    var sample:Number = event.data.readFloat();

                                    buffer.writeFloat(sample);
                                    if(buffer.length % 40000 == 0){
                                            triggerEvent('recordingProgress', recordingDuration(),  microphone.activityLevel);
                                    }       
                            }
                    }
```

What I need to do is to push every `var sample` float into the javascript function `updateMainBuff`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
ExternalInterface.call("updateMainBuff", sample);
```